# the configuration file contains a syntax error on line 14; [EParseError] ........ This Error Occurred During WampServer Startup

Tags: wamp

When I Click On WampServer Icon TO Start WampServer, It Shows the Below Errors-

```
The configuration file contains a syntax error on line 14; [EParseError] No tray icon was specified. Please assign a tray icon using the Trayicon directives in the [Config] section.
```

How do I Open WampServer Without Reinstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close The Window That Showing Error Message or Exit Error Window from Task Manager.

Run C:\wamp64\restart_wampserver.bat

and Reopen Wamp Application

Answer (score -1):

I have found that this error occurs when a power outage occurs. (Yes, I need a UPS);

If a wampmanager shutdown/restart doesn't work try the following:

Keep a duplicate of the following files in a separate folder, e.g. C:\wamp64_refresh:

```
C:\wamp64\wampmanager.conf 
C:\wamp64\wampmanager.ini 
C:\wamp64\wampmanager.tpl
```

When the error occurs, copy ALL of these files back to C:\wamp64 and then, as above, run:

```
C:\wamp64\restart_wampserver.bat
```